# Problems webview and setvisibility

Tags: android-studio, webview, apk

Setting the setVisibility option to "noti_fy" causes the application to crash. If I use an identical scheme for XML without webview, then everything is displayed perfectly. What could I have done wrong? Where is my mistake?

My XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cefmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/cefnotify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My .java code:

```
public class Notify {
    public Activity activity;
    public WebView webshow;
    public ConstraintLayout noti_fy;
    public Notify(Activity aactivity) {
        activity = aactivity;
        noti_fy = aactivity.findViewById(R.id.cefmain);
        noti_fy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webshow = noti_fy.findViewById(R.id.cefnotify);
        webshow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webshow.loadUrl("https://trident.morsel.online/pickup/index.html");

    }

    public void ShowNotify() {
        Utils.ShowLayout(noti_fy, false);

    }
}
```